# Conflicting description for gold tag badge holder's marking as duplicates

Tags: support, vote-to-close, duplicate-questions, tag-badges

There are conflicting descriptions for marking as duplicates, if you are a gold tag badge holder.

Excerpt from the [help center](/help/privileges/close-questions)

> ...except for duplicate questions, which can be marked as duplicate with a single vote from a user who has earned a gold tag badge in **one of that question's current tags**, unless that user participated in editing the tags

Excerpt from [Tim Post ♦'s answer](/a/231212/350567)

> - You can instantly close as a duplicate any question that was **originally asked with a tag** you have a gold badge for.
> - You can instantly reopen any question closed as a duplicate that was **originally asked with a tag** you have a gold badge for.

Which one of these is correct?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tim Post's answer represents the original implementation of the feature. The help center represents how the feature *currently* works. It was changed in December 2015, but that'd be more obvious if we exposed the revision history or at least when it was last updated in the help center.